# How to Determine Network Speed on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have seen several apps on the market that are allowing users to determine their current network connection speeds. How is this possible, and what might I use to be able to use this functionality? I am querying network types but I am not sure how to determine the current speed of the connections.

Comment: Without testing the connection, there's no way to know. Being connected to wifi for example doesn't mean that the internet connection is anything but a slow connection. And, testing the connection could use an expensive data plan, which would not be recommended unless the user authorized it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the `NetworkInformation` class that gives you basic information about the connectivity (network available or not, wifi enabled or not) there is no API with the current SDK for determining network speed.

I guess the apps doing this simply create a web request to download some sample files hosted on their website and measure the time it takes, etc.

Comment: In doing some more research, I see some solutions are using javascipt within a webbrowser to do what you say with an image. How might I set something like this up on my device? I do not have experience with javascript except for basic navigation in a webbrowser control.

Comment: Yes, you can interact with the webpage via ScriptNotify (Javascript to C#) and InvokeScript (C# to Javascript).

Comment: After much research/trial/ and error I have what I believe may give me the solution I need, although the value returned is `NaN`. Thought you might be able to take a look and see if anything is wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777362/calculating-speed-using-javascript-returns-nan