# Calculating speed using JavaScript returns NaN

Tags: c#, javascript, html, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

I am following the sample shown here [How to detect internet speed in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript) where an image with known file size is downloaded from the web and the speed is determined. For some reason I am not getting a result. My implementation is slightly different in that I am calling the JavaScript using InvokeScript and getting the value via ScriptNotify. My result value, however, is NaN. What can I do to fix this?

JavaScript

```
var imageAddr = "http://www.tranquilmusic.ca/images/cats/Cat2.JPG";
    var startTime, endTime;
    var downloadSize = 5616998;
    var download = new Image();
    download.onload = function () {
        endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        showResults();
    }
    startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    download.src = imageAddr;

    function showResults() {
        var duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000; //Math.round()
        var bitsLoaded = downloadSize * 8;
        var speedBps = (bitsLoaded / duration).toFixed(2);
        var speedKbps = (speedBps / 1024).toFixed(2);
        var speedMbps = (speedKbps / 1024).toFixed(2);

        window.external.notify("COT" + speedMbps);
    }
```

C#

```
private void RunTestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object connectionType = Browser.InvokeScript("showResults");
    }

private void Browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = null;
        value = e.Value.ToString();

        TempResultTextBlock.Text = value;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure this is actually your problem, but `.toFixed(2)` turns your numbers into strings.  You really ought to leave that out until the very end of your calculations and then only when you want to display a final result.

Comment: I'll try that. Would I get some sort of syntax or other error using `.toString` as opposed to `.toFixed(2)`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  You can leave off the `.toFixed()` everywhere you have it and just put it here: `window.external.notify("COT" + speedMbps.toFixed(2));`.  Then, all your numbers stay numbers like they should be.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion with the same result. Am I downloading the image properly? I cannot determine what the error may be.